# How to create custom Product Type in PrestaShop 8+?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-modules

So this is my question.

I did a little research on this, but unfortunately I did not find anything. I want my module to add a new product type to prestashop's built-in 4 types. How can i do this correct?

It will be great if provide some example modules if you have ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not currently possible to add a new product type. However, you can add modules or fields to allow your customers to choose alternative ways of selling their items.